Trying To Change SeriesCollection.Values Using Powerpoint 365 VBA
I'm trying to change the value of a single bar chart via VBA, unsuccessfully.
I can read the value but, cannot change it.
Private Sub btnTeste3_Click()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim srs As Series
    
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
    Set shp = sld.Shapes("Barra 1")
    Set ch = shp.Chart
    Set srs = ch.SeriesCollection(1)
    
    MsgBox "Nome da Forma: " & sld.Shapes("Barra 1").Name & vbNewLine & _
           "Valor: " & srs.Values(1)
    
    'None of them works but also, it doesn't raise any error.
    srs.Values(1) = 30
    srs.Values(1) = CDbl(30)
    srs.Values(1) = Array(CDbl(30))
    
    Set sld = Nothing
    Set shp = Nothing
    Set ch = Nothing
    Set srs = Nothing
End Sub

if anyone knows, please, help me.
thanks in advance.

Different solution from the other answer: instead of srs.Values(1)=30,  change the entire series with srs.Values = Array(30, x, y, z) (retrieving the remaining values first if you don't want to change them).
